# JasperReports SVG chart in HTML report

Tags: java, svg, jasper-reports, batik

Is it possible to have sharp or at least not very blurry charts in JasperReports when exported in HTML format?

I use SVG chart renderer type, which is fine for PDF exports. HTML exports remain blurry.

I tried to create SVG programaticaly with JFreeChart and BatikRenderer (using a scriptlet). I get SVG XML which i set as String variable in jrxml file and use it in image element:

```
<image scaleImage="FillFrame">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="401" y="566" width="159" height="124" uuid="1baa80f7-3151-4fb8-be85-140059e9e28e"/>
    <imageExpression>
        <![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstanceFromText($V{Chart})]]>
    </imageExpression>
</image>
```

With this approach image is still blurry (later i noticed all image resources in HTML export are in .png format).

Using code below still generates PNG image in HTML export

```
net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstanceFromText("<svg xmlns:svg=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.0\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\"><circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"40\" stroke=\"green\" stroke-width=\"4\" fill=\"yellow\" /></svg>")
```

Is there a way to use generated SVG XML inside of Jasper report or any other solution to get sharp images of charts in HTML file? I was also considering using generated SVG XML inside of TextField component with HTML markup but i don't think that's possible with all HTML tags, just basic ones like `<b>` and `<br>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with JasperReports 6.2.2 the HTML exporter will output SVG for chart elements if `net.sf.jasperreports.chart.render.type=svg` is set, and for `BatikRenderer` images.

`BatikRenderer` has actually been deprecated, you can use `net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleDataRenderer.getInstance(byte[])` instead (if you have the SVG as a `String` you'll need to pass something like `$V{Chart}.getBytes("UTF-8")`).

For older versions you can improve the quality of the rasterized SVG by setting the `net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi` property (in jasperreports.properties) to something like 300.  But that would still not be the same as having the actual SVG, so consider upgrading to the latest JasperReports.

Comment: Wow, i was using 6.2.1 version... thanks a lot! Even with Batik renderer, svg images are produced. If anyone need to update Jaspersoft Studio, it is as simple as going to Help -> Check for updates